# Which is more convenient in Hong Kong ? Stroller or baby sling?

Tags: children, hong-kong

Well, the question is in the title.

Some clarification:

The infant will be 6 months old, quite small (under 7 kgs / 15 lbs).
We'll go in September.  Will the weather be too hot then for a baby sling?  The the baby has already suffered heatstroke once while being carried during a hot day.
We'll probably use public transportation a lot--buses, minibuses and metro mostly.

I personally think a stroller will be cumbersome, but I might be wrong.

Comment: You do encounter quite a lot of stairs when walking around Hong Kong. Elevators are available in most places, but tend to be less convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No contest: **baby sling.**

Wikivoyage has an article about [travelling in Japan with children](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Japan_with_children), and the bit about travelling in dense Japanese cities applies to Hong Kong as well:

> In a nutshell, *leave your giant stroller at home*, as they can be a
>   nightmare to deal with. City sidewalks are busy, temple and shrine
>   paths are nearly invariably gravel, trains are crowded (impossibly so
>   in rush hour), and while elevators are slowly being retrofitted
>   everywhere, there are still many stations where you'll need to use the
>   stairs or take *long* detours to use the one elevator available. [...]
>
> Instead, the Japanese prefer **baby carriers**, often for children as old
>   as two, and **lightweight collapsible umbrella strollers** that fit
>   through normal ticket gates and can be carried up or down a flight of
>   stairs one-handed in a pinch.

In my own experience, umbrella strollers are handy, but require two adults to comfortably operate: eg. one climbs up stairs with baby, the other carries stroller, diaper bag, suitcase, etc.  A 6-month-old is also a bit borderline to use one for longer periods of time, try it out before you take one along.

And yes, September will be hot.  If you're feeling uncomfortably hot, the baby will be feeling so as well.  Fortunately virtually everything in HK is air-conditioned.